# How to open and play/stream a midi file using using Android MidiManager

Tags: android, midi

I am attempting to write an Android application where part of it is to open a midi file, and have this play to an external device.

Following [this information](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/package-summary) I am able to open the device, and get it to play a note, but I cannot find anything (that works) to open an actual midi file and steam this (in real time so plays back on an external device)

I have tried [this](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/sound/play-midi-audio/) but the imports

```
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.Sequencer;
```

are not found.

I have looked at [this](https://github.com/LeffelMania/android-midi-lib), but just don't see how to import/use it.

I am quite new to this. Are examples available for this?

### Update

I found [this](https://github.com/kshoji/javax.sound.midi-for-Android/), and can now add and execute the code [from here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/sound/play-midi-audio/), but is not playing anything... so I am not sure how the "connect" the `Sequencer` to the midi device I have opened (and I know this midi device is working, as when I write to `MidiInputPort.send` I get a note playing on my external keyboard with the the wireless midi cable).

Comment: Those are java imports.  You want Android ones.  I'm not sure what those translate into, but Android does not include all Java libraries.  Although I'd think MidiReceiver looks promising to look into.

Comment: I'd be very cautious about "finding" random libraries on github.  THe last time any code file in that project has been touched was 11 months ago.    There were 4 contributions in 2021, and none before that since 2016.  Basically, its a dead project.  I really wouldn't put random github libraries you aren't knowledgeable enough to audit into your program unless they're widely used-  its asking for security issues and bugs.

Comment: Yes, I would much prefer to just know how to code it myself, but I just can't find a single example or documentation. Seems like should be such a common thing to want to do (for a midi application)

Answer (score 0):

I'll include what I have got to work, I am sure there may be a better way.

I managed to get [this library](https://github.com/LeffelMania/android-midi-lib) included and working, and this looks after reading the midi events and dispatching them to a callback at the correct time (the most complicated part). Then, once you have an `inputPort`, following [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/package-summary), I could get my single track playing all the notes on one MIDI channel.

So some purely test, and **very not production ready code** I used looked like this...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
  MidiManager m = (MidiManager)getSystemService(Context.MIDI_SERVICE);
  MidiDeviceInfo[] infos = m.getDevices();
  if (infos.length > 0) {
    m.openDevice(infos[0],
        new MidiManager.OnDeviceOpenedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDeviceOpened(MidiDevice device) {
                int i = 0;
                MidiInputPort inputPort = device.openInputPort(0);

                try {
                    // This plays the file
                    playMidi(inputPort);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ....
                                
                
private void playMidi(MidiInputPort inputPort) throws FileNotFoundException {
String music = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getAbsolutePath();
    File input = new File(music + "/test.mid");
    try {
        MidiFile midi = new MidiFile(input);
        MidiProcessor processor = new MidiProcessor(midi);

        // listen for all midi events:
        processor.registerEventListener(new MidiEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStart(boolean fromBeginning) {
            }

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onEvent(MidiEvent event, long ms) {
                if (event.getClass() == NoteOn.class) {
                    NoteOn noteOn = ((NoteOn) event);
                    try {
                        ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage();
                        msg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 1, noteOn.getNoteValue(), noteOn.getVelocity());
                        int len = msg.getLength();
                        byte[] bytes = msg.getMessage();
                        int offset = 0;
                        inputPort.send(bytes, offset, len);
                    } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else if (event.getClass() == NoteOff.class) {
                    NoteOff noteOff = ((NoteOff) event);
                    try {
                        ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage();
                        msg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 1, noteOff.getNoteValue(), noteOff.getVelocity());
                        int len = msg.getLength();
                        byte[] bytes = msg.getMessage();
                        int offset = 0;
                        inputPort.send(bytes, offset, len);
                    } catch (InvalidMidiDataException | IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStop(boolean finished) {
            }
        }, MidiEvent.class);


        processor.start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

So we use the `onEvent` from the above library, and then we can get the raw information required to play into `inputPort.send`.

With the above, and also running [this utility app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobileer.example.midibtlepairing), and using a Yamaha MD-BT01 Bluetooth Wireless MIDI Adaptor (its say for iOS, but works fine with my Pixel 3A Android phone), I got the midi file playing into my external keyboard (with the MD-BT01 plugged in)